# No bezier handles showing up in F curve editor

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, fcurves

Please help there are no handles at all. I've set the interpolation to Bezier a million times nothing is happening please help.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh I accidently pressed Ctrl H.

Ctrl-H will show/hide the bezier curve handles in the graph editor. It can be found in the graph editors view menu.

Comment: would you please elaborate, edit your answer. If would be more useful to others with a bit more detail.